# Pair popup still appear even already paired device with BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having a problem with an Android <> BLE device, every time request read a character then popup pair will appear.
Expectation: if Android paired with BLE then normal reading without pairing popup
Thank!

Comment: Is the GATT Server returning "Insufficient authentication" error code maybe?